# Should I use Centos 7 or Centos 8 on my VPS Server for Plesk?

Tags: centos, centos7, vps, centos8, plesk

I'm going to buy a VPS from a company. It asks me if you want to choose Centos 7 or Centos 8 when purchasing VPS. From what I've researched on the internet, there is no difference between the two. But I didn't really trust what was written on the internet. If there is no difference, why would Centos 8 come out?

My question is, should I use Centos 7 or Centos 8 to install Linux VPS Plesk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that easy. CentOS 8 is obviously newer and contains newer packages, but due to policy changes by RedHat it has been cancelled and replaced by CentOS Stream. CentOS 8 will reach it's end of life in December 2021, there will be no security updates anymore after that.
CentOS 7, while older, will receive security updates (but no feature updates) until 2024.

Comment: Which one do you prefer?

Comment: Personal opinions are off topic. But to be honest, neither is acceptable for me anymore.